# How to get file name which have error using AWK command?

Tags: bash, awk

I am using the SAC tool to read the header information but some files have no header information and it prints an error.
Is there any way to use AWK to print that files if they do not have a header or error during work. I often used AWK for data manipulation but failed this time.

Here is my try:

```
saclst a f *2020-05*BHZ*
```

This is the output

```
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T03:52.BHZ.sac         3.37
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T09:28.BHZ.sac         3.64
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T12:09.BHZ.sac         3.42
saclst: Error determining SAC header: GS.GS043.2020-05-18T14:36.BHZ.sac
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T16:25.BHZ.sac         2.92
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T18:51.BHZ.sac         3.66
```

Now I want to get the file name and print it but seems like AWK does not help;

```
saclst a f *2020-05*BHZ* | awk '{if ($2<0) print $1;}' > ../test.dat
```

My output file is empty and the terminal shows this error:

Is there any way to save this error so I can later modify it?

```
saclst: Error determining SAC header: SC.LZB.2020-05-21T10:46.BHZ.sac
saclst: Error determining SAC header: SC.LZB.2020-05-21T11:57.BHZ.sac
saclst: Error determining SAC header: SC.LZB.2020-05-26T11:23.BHZ.sac
saclst: Error determining SAC header: SC.LZB.2020-05-28T10:44.BHZ.sac
saclst: Error determining SAC header: SC.QSC.2020-05-12T06:49.BHZ.sac
```

Comment: I don't know about SAC and your question is not clear about what is wrong the output you got. I'm not sure how you got that output since you are printing `$1`, so you should have got only `saclst:` instead of entire line.

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for the comment. Actually, I can not save this error in the file for further modification as the output file is just empty. This error is in the terminal

Comment: Error messages go to standard error, not standard output; to pipe them to Awk, you need something like `saclst args 2>&1 >elsewhere | awk ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I *think* you are looking for:

```sh
# just for demo, pipe SAC tool to awk for your actual use case
$ cat ip.txt
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T03:52.BHZ.sac         3.37
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T09:28.BHZ.sac         3.64
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T12:09.BHZ.sac         3.42
saclst: Error determining SAC header: GS.GS043.2020-05-18T14:36.BHZ.sac
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T16:25.BHZ.sac         2.92
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T18:51.BHZ.sac         3.66

# filter lines with Error based on number of fields or `Error` in 2nd field
$ awk 'NF != 2' ip.txt
saclst: Error determining SAC header: GS.GS043.2020-05-18T14:36.BHZ.sac
$ awk '$2 == "Error"' ip.txt
saclst: Error determining SAC header: GS.GS043.2020-05-18T14:36.BHZ.sac

# print only last field
$ awk '$2 == "Error"{print $NF}' ip.txt
GS.GS043.2020-05-18T14:36.BHZ.sac
```

If the `saclst` command puts the lines with `Error` on `stderr`, you can use this:

```sh
$ saclst a f *2020-05*BHZ* 2> error.log
```

Comment: again thanks for your effort. But I could not save the error in the output file e.g ip.txt.   SAC is just a tool for seismic data analysis (Seismic Analysis Code).

Comment: you have to use `saclst a f *2020-05*BHZ* | awk '...'` or perhaps you mean those `Error` lines are actually on `stderr`? Try `saclst a f *2020-05*BHZ* 2> error.log` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Athough `awk` (what you asked) works,

```
sed -n 's/.*Error.*:/ /p' ip.txt
```

would work fine as well. And

```
grep Error ip.txt
```

So, don't focus on using only `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna cleanup that awk code (assuming +$2 is correct), try

```
saclst ... 2>&1 | [g/m/n]awk '(+$2<+_)*(NF=!_)'
```

The reason why I'm suggesting the `+$2` is that inputs being read in would do a string-based-comparison if that values don't "appear" numeric, leading to the following scenario where invalid data like an exclamation mark `!` preceding the numbers in column 2 would end up having the condition evaluate to true, even though it's clearly not a negative number

- `!` is **\x21**
- ASCII `0` is **\x30**

that's why it ended up passing the filter unintentionally :

```
 echo '12 !232523435 2997 ' \
 \
 | mawk '$2<0'

 12 !232523435 2997
```

Now that's only assuming OP's original logic of checking $2 being negative is accurate.

To properly handle ip.txt, I tested this other variant instead:

```
% < ip.txt [g/m/n]awk '/: .+: .+:/ && ($!_=$_=$NF)~_'

GS.GS043.2020-05-18T14:36.BHZ.sac
```

I created a synthetic version of ip.txt that's 8.27 GB in size.  Maybe grep or sed is faster, but personally me thinks a filtering throughput rate of 532 MB/s for awk should be plenty :

```
 pvE0 <  ip2.txt | mawk2 '/: .+: .+:/ && ($!_=$_=$NF)~_' | pvE9 | xxh128sum 

      in0: 8.27GiB 0:00:15 [ 532MiB/s] [ 532MiB/s]             
     out9:  938MiB 0:00:15 [59.0MiB/s] [59.0MiB/s] [        <=>  ]

e8626c6b7e7c90a5cb21bd00fee6ec41  stdin
```